# Sqlite local Storage Issue in Ionic 3 Application

Tags: angular, typescript, sqlite, ionic3, local-storage

I need to show some **offline data's (without network connection)** inside my ionic application.

Initially , all data's loaded from ***API (backend data)*** .

So,I applied ***Sqlite (local Storage)*** concept to reproduce that same  loaded data's ...

Whenever , i want to runs the application it produce the following error ...

```
Object => InsertId:Undefined
```

How can i fix this ...,

**The code which i used into my application followed by..,**

```
addData(){
  this.sqlite.create({
    name:'sample.db',
    location:'default'
  }).then((db:SQLiteObject)=>{
    db.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history',).then((data=>{
      console.log('deleted');
      console.log(data);
    })).catch(e=>console.log(e));

    db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history(insertId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,app_history_title TEXT,app_history_content TEXT,app_history_image TEXT)',)
    .then(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      console.log('created');
    }).catch(e=>console.log(e));


  db.executeSql('INSERT INTO history VALUES(?,?,?)',['Stores with stingy',
 'It's that feeling of leaving of money on the table. Like many of us, Donna Rosato, senior editor of the money team for Consumer Reports, has experienced it before. ',
'default.jpg'])
  .then(data=>{
    console.log('inserted');
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(e=>console.log(e));

    this.localget()
  }).catch(e=>console.log(e));
}
```

**Hope anyone can solve this... Thanks in Advance..!**

Comment: `'It's that feeling of leaving of money on the table. Like many of us, Donna Rosato, senior editor of the money team for Consumer Reports, has experienced it before. '` I think you need to escape a `'` here.. Also you probably need to do the delete,create and insert _sequentially_

Comment: ok ,I will try that

Comment: thank u ,error is solved,  @SurajRao